Evaluating $\int_a^b \left[x^x\leq y\right] \, dx$ where $a$, $b$ and $y$ are real
I am trying to evaluate:
$\int_a^b \left[x^x\leq y\right] \, dx$
where $[k]$ denotes the Iverson bracket notation, $a$, $b$ and $y$ are real.
I could find the solution for the equation $x^x=y$ using a CAS as:
$(e^{W(\log (y))},e^{W_{-1}(\log (y))})$ for $e^{-1/e}\leq y<1$ and $e^{W(\log (y))}$ for $y>1$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.
Using this information I can solve the integral when $a$, $b$ and $y$ have specific numerical values. But I would like to find a general solution ($a$, $b$, and $y$ are not specified) if possible.
Note that for $a<0, b<0$, the integral is $0$.
Thanks for any help.

What do you mean a general solution? This is an indefinite integral, even if it was a nice function it would be unlikely to have a nice symbolic answer.

The lower and upper limits are $a$ and $b$ respectively. Did I misunderstand when you said that it is an indefinite integral? I was hoping to find an expression as we find in the case of e.g. $\int_a^b \lfloor x\rfloor  , dx$ ($a$ and $b$ are reals). $\int_a^b \lfloor x\rfloor  , dx$ ($a$, $b$ are real numbers) is $\frac{1}{2} (\lfloor a\rfloor  (\lfloor a\rfloor -2 a+1)+(-\lfloor b\rfloor +2 b-1) \lfloor b\rfloor )$. Such general formulae are quite handy.

what do you think an indefinite integral is.

Indefinite integral is an integral which is defined up to an additive arbitrary constant (we can omit "additive" for generality). The integral under discussion has a definite unique value defined in terms of the parameters that appear in the expression. Apologies for any confusion, willing to be corrected...

There is, in terms of solving the problem, literally no difference between an indefinite integral and an integral with free variables as its bounds.

That is correct (but is different from what you said in the first comment). Note that this is a piecewise function which takes only $0$ and 1 as its values. If we can determine this behavior in the real line, we can solve the problem. I am working it out based on the solution of the equation I mentioned in the post, but it is getting complex. I was hoping if someone could come up with a more intelligent technique.
